# AWS EC2 Instance not showing as FQDN or I.P

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

So I've went through countless forums and threads to tweak my settings to find a solution, but now I'm stuck. I can't get my domain (stork.io) to map over my I.P. address (Elastic) for my instance. Entering the domain and I.P. both show "Not able to connect to the server"

I've set my inbound port 80 for all I.P. address's, and from the looks of my Nginx config it seems to be normal. I've also set the name severs at my registrar as well as added the domain into Route 53 along with the required A record point to the server I.P.

If someone could point something out or suggest anything that I may be missing, I will gladly check and correct anything I may find.

Answer (score 0):

The propagation of your changes to DNS resolvers can take 24+ hours. What is the TTL setting for the name servers for the parent domain?

Comment: It's been well over 24 hours. My TTL setting is set to 300 which is the default for a zone on AWS.